# Error in setsockopt(): Numerical argument out of domain

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a working code running on a RedHat installed Linux with kernel **2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP x86_64**.

When I moved the code to a newly installed machine with CentOS 6.3 the same code failed with

> Error assigning socket option: **Numerical argument out of domain**

The kernel version of the latter machine is **2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP**

Below is the code of what's both working and failing in the machines, respectively.

```
    struct timeval          tv;

    tv.tv_sec       = 0;
    tv.tv_usec      = 1500000;

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(struct timeval)) != 0)
    {
            LM_ERR("Error assigning socket option: %s", strerror( errno ));
            return FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using

```
tv.tv_sec       = 1;
tv.tv_usec      = 500000;
```

I've seen some implementations not accepting `tv_usec` above 10^6.

**Edit:** The issue is interesting enough to dig a little bit. Looking for `SO_RCVTIMEO` in the kernel source code I've found the following piece of code in `net/core/sock.c`:

```
int sock_setsockopt(struct socket *sock, int level, int optname,
            char __user *optval, unsigned int optlen)
{

   / ... /    
   switch (optname) {

   / ... /    

   case SO_RCVTIMEO:
        ret = sock_set_timeout(&sk->sk_rcvtimeo, optval, optlen);
        break;

   / ... /    
}
```

The beginning of the `sock_set_timeout()` function indeed contains some range checking:

```
static int sock_set_timeout(long *timeo_p, char __user *optval, int optlen)
{
    struct timeval tv;

    if (optlen < sizeof(tv))
        return -EINVAL;
    if (copy_from_user(&tv, optval, sizeof(tv)))
        return -EFAULT;
    if (tv.tv_usec < 0 || tv.tv_usec >= USEC_PER_SEC)
        return -EDOM;

    /* ... */
}
```

Now we know enough to do some `git blame`-ing :) The change was introduced with the following changeset:

```
commit ba78073e6f70cd9c64a478a9bd901d7c8736cfbc 
Author: Vasily Averin <vvs@sw.ru> 
Date:   Thu May 24 16:58:54 2007 -0700

[NET]: "wrong timeout value" in sk_wait_data() v2

sys_setsockopt() do not check properly timeout values for 
SO_RCVTIMEO/SO_SNDTIMEO, for example it's possible to set negative timeout
values. POSIX do not defines behaviour for sys_setsockopt in case negative
timeouts, but requires that setsockopt() shall fail with -EDOM if the send and
receive timeout values are too big to fit into the timeout fields in the socket
structure. 
In current implementation negative timeout can lead to error messages like
"schedule_timeout: wrong timeout value".

Proposed patch:
- checks tv_usec and returns -EDOM if it is wrong
- do not allows to set negative timeout values (sets 0 instead) and outputs
  ratelimited information message about such attempts.

Signed-off-By: Vasily Averin <vvs@sw.ru>
Signed-off-by: David S. Miller <davem@davemloft.net>
```

I believe that the commit comment explains everything. As far as I can see this change was included in 2.6.22-rc3.

Comment: This way works. But the question remains: why does this was working in my previous installation?

Comment: I've seen this problem myself (with `select()`, afair) - I believe the implementation simply changed at some point, either as a result of some bug fixed, or perhaps to improve compliance, etc.

Comment: Thank you! it definitively answer my question in every aspect. Thanks again :)

Comment: This was almost a DenverCoder9 problem for me. Thanks for debugging. Why doesn't the kernel just modulo the us value into the ms value? i.e. a tv_usec of 1000001 would just be treated as 1 s + 1 us

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't that be

```
tv.tv_sec   = 1;
tv.tv_usec  = 500000;
```

since 1 million microseconds == 1 second?

Comment: yes, but isn't it strange that it works previous versions of the kernel?